# Express Router.use in middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Express.

I am trying to route a request according to a value in DB. To do this I am calling a service function.
Routing is working successfully but I am loosing the request object.
I have tried to pass the req to the service but it didn't work.

Any help showing how to do this would be nice.

Here is my code block.

```
var companyService = require("services/companyService");
router.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
companyService.isCompanyOnline(req.body.companyCode).then(function (company) {
    if (company) {
        router.use('/', require("api/controllers/online"));
    }
    else {
        router.use('/', require("api/controllers/offline"));
    }
});
next();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Services.companyService:

```
function isCompanyOnline(code) {
var deferred = Q.defer();
companies.findOne({ companyCode: code }, function (err, company) {
    if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
    //if (err) throw err;
    if (company) {
        // return company online parameter
        deferred.resolve(company.isOnline);
    } else {
        // company not found
        deferred.resolve();
    }
});
return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: **Where** are you losing the `req` object? Or better: where are you trying to access the `req` object?

Comment: @tmslnz in `api/controllers/online` or `api/controllers/online` routes.

Comment: Well then… away to reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing the request object because you are not passing it anywhere.

I believe your main issue here is the fact that you have **three** route handlers registering on the same path `/`. If I am not mistaken they will be all called in-order that you add them. But the order in your depends on the `if` you are placing the `router.use()` calls. So it's unpredictable, and likely not going to work as you expect. **Once they are registered they stay in the middleware stack** until you restart the app.

I suggest you refactor to have the online/offline logic in one place, or register all your middlewares at once, so you *know* in which order they get called, and use `next()` accordingly.

**On another note, if you want to pass an argument to `require`d modules, do this:**

Change `api/controllers/online` and the other, to accept an argument, and return the handler function that you are passing.

```
// your code in api/controllers/online and offline

module.exports = function (req) {
    // now you have req available in-scope here
    function yourFunctionThatNeedsReq (req) {
        // do stuff with req
    }
    return yourFunctionThatNeedsReq;
};
```

Then update your `require` like so. Note the `…(req)`.

```
router.use('/', require("api/controllers/online")(req) );
```

Comment: That last bit won't work. You're calling the function at declaration time, when there is not yet a request. If you just do:  app.use('/', require('./api/controllers/online')) you'll get the effect you described

Comment: @Paul Not too sure you're correct… `require(…)` returns a "factory", `factory(req)` returns the route handler with the request object passed in by the factory. – Additionally it appears to have worked for the OP.

Comment: @tmslnz I understand the concept of a factory function. What I'm saying is that you're calling that function at the point that you are mounting the middleware, but there is no request variable in scope at that point.  Try it out if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

First, define routes:

```
app.use('/api/online', require("api/controllers/online"));
app.use('/api/offline', require("api/controllers/offline"));
```

Then change the url in the router :

```
if (req.body.companyInfo.isOnline) {
        req.url = '/online' + req.url + '/' + req.body.companyInfo.companyPath;
        next();
    }
    else {
        req.url = '/offline' + req.url + '/' + req.body.companyInfo.companyPath;
        next();
    }
```